# can't call method inside a for each loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm relearning javascript from playing this game

http://play.elevatorsaga.com/

doc: http://play.elevatorsaga.com/documentation.html#docs

currently trying to beat level 4 where there are two elevators and I want to use a for each loop to go through each elevator object, then call the methods to do stuff like:

```
            var maxFloor = 7;
            var basement = 0;
            // when each elevator is idle, go to each floor
            for each(var e in elevators){
                e.on("idle", function() {
                    //The elevator is idle, so let's go to all the floors (or did we forget one?)
                    for(var i = basement; i < maxFloor; i++){
                        e.goToFloor(i);     
                    }
                });
            }
```

why is this not compiling? when the `__.on()` method was called outside of the `for each` loop everything worked. Is there something fundamental I'm missing for javascript?

Thanks

Comment: `e` isn't what you think it is when the 2nd loop happens.

Comment: @KevinB hmm, isn't `e` an `elevator`? thanks

Comment: It will always be the last one, not the one you expect it to be. It will also be the index of the array, not the value.

Comment: @KevinB I see, I was able to get it to work with plain `for` loop and treating the `var` as an `int` and that worked. thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a few errors here:

- depending on your browser, `for each` should read `for`
- the `for-in` construct iterates over collections (i.e. arrays and objects) and passes the "index" to the variable named before `in`. In your code if `elevators` is an array of elevator objects like this `elevators = [elevator1, elevator2, ..., elevatorN]`, each time the `for-in` loops `e` will be the index of the elevator meaning `e = 0, then e = 1, ..., e = n`.  So, try naming `e`, `i` and in the beginning of the loop declare `var e = elevators[i]` and your code should work.

Comment: Isn't `for each` also acceptable?https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Ffor_each...in I realized my error in treating the index as its value, thanks!

Comment: If you look at the bottom table `for each` is only supported in Firefox, gotta love javascript. ;-)